# Cannot implicitly convert type string

Tags: c#

I keep getting this error on the second prepopulated... Cannot implicity convert type string to System.Collections.Generic.IEnumerable and I am unsure of what I am doing wrong.

```
namespace HomeInventory2
{
    public partial class Form1 : Form
    {
        public Form1(string prepopulated)
        {
            InitializeComponent();
            IEnumerable<String> lines = prepopulated;
            textBoxAmount.Text = lines.ElementAtOrDefault(0);
            textBoxCategories.Text = lines.ElementAtOrDefault(1);
            textBoxProperties.Text = lines.ElementAtOrDefault(2);
            textBoxValue.Text = lines.ElementAtOrDefault(3);
        }

        private void label1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {

        }

        private void submitButton_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            CreateInventory create = new CreateInventory();
            create.ItemAmount = textBoxAmount.Text;
            create.ItemCategory = textBoxCategories.Text;
            create.ItemProperties = textBoxValue.Text;
            create.ItemValue = textBoxValue.Text;

            InventoryMngr invtryMngr = new InventoryMngr();
            invtryMngr.Create(create);

        }
    }
```

Comment: Did you read the message?

Comment: Is it a compilation error or a runtime error?

Comment: What is `prepopulated` filled with?  What do you expect to be in `lines`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have your constructor taking a single string as a parameter:

```
public Form1(string prepopulated)
```

You then are trying to set this to an `IEnumerable<string>`:

```
IEnumerable<String> lines = prepopulated;
```

You need to, instead, pass in an `IEnumerable<string>`:

```
public Form1(IEnumerable<string> prepopulated)
```

If your `prepopulated` string is a string which can be parsed into multiple strings, you could do that instead.  For example, if it's "prepopulated" with a string with newline separations, you could instead do something like:

```
IEnumerable<String> lines = prepopulated.Split(new[] {'\n'}, StringSplitOptions.RemoveEmptyEntries); // Split into separate lines
```

Answer (score 4):

This line

```
IEnumerable<String> lines = prepopulated;
```

**prepopulated** is a string and you are trying to assign it to a List of strings. Maybe you want to **Split()** it first?  Or maybe your Form's constructor should take a List of strings to begin with.

Answer (score 3):

You are trying to assign `string` to `IEnumerable<string>` here:

```
public Form1(string prepopulated)
{
    // ...
    IEnumerable<string> lines = prepopulated;
    // ...
}
```

You should refactor contructor to something like this:

```
public Form1(IEnumerable<string> prepopulated)
{
    // ...
    IEnumerable<string> lines = prepopulated;
    // ...
}
```

Comment: Yeah - I suspect that's the case, too - most of the votes had this happen.

Comment: you cannot be serious? if you look at this guy profile he has 6 questions asking for the same code over and over again, and piece by piece from all the answers you will eventually get this code. I can understand you want to help, but pulling the, he someone is downvoting a legit answer card is stupid. no one should have answered this question and it should be flagged, as should his profile.

Comment: @Rikkos do you really think I am tracking every person posting a question? I saw his question and I've answered, which seems rather normal to me. Really, I don't understand you, I (and others) should be downvoted because he is posting *wrong* (at least for you) question? ;)

Answer (score 1):

As the error message clearly states, you cannot assign a `string` to an `IEnumerable<String>`.

You may want to call `.Split()`.

Answer (score 0):

You can't add to the IEnumerable but you can do something of the following.

```
IEnumerable<String> lines = new List<string>();
//or
//IEnumerable<String> lines = Enumerable.Empty<string>();
//IEnumerable<String> lines = Enumerable.Repeat("My string",1); //only single value
//IEnumerable<String> lines = new string[] {"My string","My other string"}

//or
var lines = new List<string>();
lines.Add("My string");
lines.Add("My other string");   

IEnumerable<String> ienumLines = lines;
return ienumLines;

//or add an extension method

public static void AddRange<T>(this ICollection<T> collection, IEnumerable<T> items) 
{
    foreach(T item in items) 
    {
       collection.Add(item);
    }
}
```

Regards

Comment: There is no "add" method in `IEnumerable<T>`, nor is this an object you can create via `new`, as it's an *interface*.

Answer (score 0):

Try passing the parameter `prepopulated` as of type `IEnumerable<String>`

```
public Form1(IEnumerable<String> prepopulated)
{
    InitializeComponent();
    IEnumerable<String> lines = prepopulated;
    // ....
}
```

OR

Assuming your string is like `ABC, DEF, GHI`, then you can do something like this:

```
// where String Split is based on comma (,)
IEnumerable<String> lines = prepopulated.Split(new[] { ',' }, 
    StringSplitOptions.RemoveEmptyEntries).Select(s => s.Trim());
```

You get the result:

```
ABC
DEF
GHI
```